# Static Library throws Linker Error: "No such file or directory"

Tags: ios, xcode

Background (may or may not be relevant): I'm trying to use a trans-compiler called [j2objc](https://code.google.com/p/j2objc/) that allows you to translate Java code for use in iOS applications. Its base library contains a bunch of objective-c translations of the Java Runtime. In order to add that codebase, [according to its wiki](https://code.google.com/p/j2objc/wiki/JreEmulationXcode) I should add the provided `.xcodeproj` as a static library. That's where I'm having trouble.

What I've done:

- added the provided `.xcodeproj` as a child project
- Under the `Build Phases` of my primary target, under `Target Dependencies`, I've added the appropriate target form the child project
- Under `Link Binary with Libraries` I added a file called `libjre_emul.a` which is the supposed output of the child project.
- This is all per the project's instructions and goes according to plan

What fails: When I try to build the project, I get the following error:

> clang: error: no such file or directory:
>       '/Users/Thomas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tuxblocks-asszlcvjgdqugifxhbkkwcrstotk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libjre_emul.a'

In fact there is no `libjre_emul.a` in that folder, so Xcode is right. When I build the child project by itself I get no build errors, so I assume its doing what it's supposed to, but I also have checked its output folders and see no `libjre_emul.a` there either. So why isn't the output library there?

One point that may be relevant: It seems the library I'm trying to use was created in Xcode 3, and I'm using Xcode 4. I've heard there might be some problems there.

I confess I'm a newbie with Xcode, so I may be misunderstanding something completely. In any case, I certainly appreciate your help!

EDIT: I've found the `libjre_emul.a` file. It's in a folder under the subproject called build_result. Copying it into to where Xcode expects it seems to let it run...

Comment: Had the same problem, copying it into the directory fixed it. Thanks! :)

Comment: make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/Users/Prem/.m2/repository/com/ibm/icu/icu4j/51.1/icu4j-51.1-sources.jar', needed by `/Users/Prem/Desktop/j2objc-0.8.5/java_deps/build_result/icu4j-51.1-sources.jar'.  Stop.

Comment: I get the above error with wiki steps and hence the build fails... looks like it has got to do something with static library compilation.

Comment: I ended up going a different route and using a precompiled library rather than trying to add their project as a subproject. For that reason, I can't really comment on whether solutions will fix the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the xcode settings, search for the build setting "Header Search Paths" and then add the directory that your static framework is in. Make sure you tell it to be recursive to help search it's subfolders.